# Scaling property of Laplace transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

I am not sure how to do the following problem:

Let $$\hat{F}(s)=\mathfrak{L}(f(t))$$ be the Laplace transform of $f(t)$. Show that:

$$\mathfrak{L}(f(at))=\frac{1}{a}\hat{F}\left(\frac{s}{a}\right) $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a change of variables in the integral. Scale with $a$:
$$
\mathcal L (f(at))(s)=\int_0^{+\infty}f(at)e^{-st}\,dt=\{u=at\}=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{+\infty}f(u)e^{-(s/a)u}\,du=\frac{1}{a}\mathcal L(f(t))(s/a).
$$

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!! Would you have any idea about this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392500/finding-the-fourier-transform-with-radial-coordinate

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

From the definition, $\mathcal{L}\{f(at)\}$ is an improper integral, try this with the sustitution $r=at$, then
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(at)\,dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{s}{a}r}f(r)\frac{1}{a}dr$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathfrak{L}(f(at))=\int_0^\infty f(at)e^{-st}dt$$

Let $u=at$ then $dt=du/a$, so:
$$\mathfrak{L}(f(at))=\int_0^\infty f(u)e^{-(s/a)u}\frac {du} a=\frac1 a \hat{F}(\frac s a)$$

Comment: In the exponential, how did you go from exp(-st) to exp(-s/a)t?

Comment: @JacksonHart Sorry, it should be $e^{-(s/a)u}$ not $t$. It's due to the substitution.

Comment: Ok that is what I thought - thanks!

Comment: You would not know how to do this one would you?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392500/finding-the-fourier-transform-with-radial-coordinate